# Using autofac in asp.net core 2.2

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, autofac

I am trying to use latest Autofac with asp.net core 2.2 project. However documentation of autofac seems to be outdated.
I am trying to use autofac without ConfigureContainer:

```
// ConfigureServices is where you register dependencies. This gets
  // called by the runtime before the Configure method, below.
  public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    // Add services to the collection.
    services.AddMvc();

    // Create the container builder.
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    // Register dependencies, populate the services from
    // the collection, and build the container.
    //
    // Note that Populate is basically a foreach to add things
    // into Autofac that are in the collection. If you register
    // things in Autofac BEFORE Populate then the stuff in the
    // ServiceCollection can override those things; if you register
    // AFTER Populate those registrations can override things
    // in the ServiceCollection. Mix and match as needed.
    builder.Populate(services);
    builder.RegisterType<MyType>().As<IMyType>();
    this.ApplicationContainer = builder.Build();

    // Create the IServiceProvider based on the container.
    return new AutofacServiceProvider(this.ApplicationContainer);
  }
```

but the ConfigureServices method signature is different in asp.net core 2.2

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
}
```

there is not return type.
Anyone knows how to use autofac in asp.net core 2.2?

Comment: `ConfigureServices` is a convention method, you can change it to return a service provider and it will still work. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#default-service-container-replacement

Comment: Even the documentation shows how to do it with out ConfigureContainer https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#quick-start-without-configurecontainer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use this package:

> Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection

In your program.cs, just use these lines of code:

```
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddAutofac());
    }
```

In your startup.cs, create a method called

```
    public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
    }
```

And use "builder" to register whatever you want.  Autofac will find this method itself.

You don't need to call any `builder.Build()` anymore.

**Following remarks in order to execute reccurent code with injected values, you need to add**:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddHostedService<MyHostedService>();
    ...
}

public class MyHostedService : IHostedService
{
    private Timer _timer;
    private IInjectedService _myInjectedService;

    public MyHostedService(IServiceProvider services)
    {
        var scope = services.CreateScope();

        _myInjectedService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IInjectedService>();
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async void DoWork(object state)
    {
        _myInjectedService.DoStuff();
    }
}
```

Comment: OP specifically stated they want to avoid using `ConfigureContainer`

Comment: in my app I have a service that runs every five minutes. How do I resolve it? It is not part of any controller. It is a singleton service that runs every n minutes. Using the approach you mentioned above I can not do this since I dont have a reference to the IContainer object

Comment: @pantonis just added the code using injection thanks to parameters (without access to IContainer)

Comment: @hugo there is a race condition when there are HostedServices since they are added to the ConfigureServices and my autofac registers are added to the ConfigureContainer which is called after the ConfigureServices.

Comment: @pantonis the ConfigureServices is called before the ConfigureContainer but not the creation of the HostedService (at least, I have no problem with my projects under dotnet core 2.x

Comment: @hugo and how can I get IContainer object to create some scopes?

Comment: Use the IServiceProvider